# problem with rails server command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I am new to working with Ruby on Rails.  I am attempting to run the rails server command and keep coming up with this error:

```
Toran1$ pwd
/Users/Toran1/Sites/simple_cms
Toran1$ rails server
NOTE: Gem::Specification#default_executable= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::Specification#default_executable= called from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/specifications/rubygems-update-1.8.2.gemspec:11.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#default_executable= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::Specification#default_executable= called from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/specifications/rubygems-update-1.8.2.gemspec:11.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#default_executable= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::Specification#default_executable= called from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/specifications/rubygems-update-1.8.2.gemspec:11.
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.2/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle: dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.2/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.2/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.2/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.2/lib/mysql2.rb:8
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.13/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.13/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.13/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.13/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.13/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.13/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.13/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `require'
    from /Users/Toran1/Sites/simple_cms/config/application.rb:7
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:28
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:27
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6
```

I have reinstalled all the gems and here is my gemlist:

```
Toran1$ gem list
NOTE: Gem::Specification#default_executable= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::Specification#default_executable= called from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/specifications/rubygems-update-1.8.2.gemspec:11.

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

NOTE: Gem::Specification#default_executable= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::Specification#default_executable= called from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/specifications/rubygems-update-1.8.2.gemspec:11.
abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.0.7)
actionpack (3.0.7)
activemodel (3.0.7)
activerecord (3.0.7)
activeresource (3.0.7)
activesupport (3.0.7)
arel (2.0.9)
builder (2.1.2)
bundler (1.0.13)
cgi_multipart_eof_fix (2.5.0)
daemons (1.1.3)
erubis (2.6.6)
fastthread (1.0.7)
gem_plugin (0.2.3)
i18n (0.5.0)
mail (2.2.19)
mime-types (1.16)
mongrel (1.1.5)
mysql2 (0.3.2)
polyglot (0.3.1)
rack (1.2.2)
rack-mount (0.6.14)
rack-test (0.5.7)
rails (3.0.7)
railties (3.0.7)
rake (0.8.7)
rubygems-update (1.8.2)
rvm (1.6.9)
thor (0.14.6)
treetop (1.4.9)
tzinfo (0.3.27)
```

If someone with more experience could just point me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it.  I have been working on this install for days!

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the MySQL client libraries installed? `Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib` indicates that you don't or they can't be found.

Comment: actually It's gotten worse, after further tinkering I now have total sql death:

Comment: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2

Comment: Have you tried switching your application over to SQLite to see if that works without issue? Have you uninstalled and then reinstalled the MySQL packages?

Answer (score 1):

Silly question but: you have installed the mysql gem, but have you actually installed the mysql application yet?

The mysql gem is just some code that talks to the existing application that you must install on your system.